# Using jQuery Lib in bbUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

When I saw the question and answer from :

[Problem jQuery with bbUI.js](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/how-where-to-use-jquery-with-webworks-and-bbui/m-p/1940309#M29908)

I want to ask.

Is the replacement syntax as in the question (using normal jQuery) :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#Div1").click(function () {
        alert("Hello world!");
   });
});
```

And replaced as in section in bbUI :

```
ondomready: function(element, id) {
    if (id == 'home') {
        $("#Div1").click(function () {
            alert("Hello world!");
        });
    }
}
```

Did not cause long syntax in index.htm file ???

Because I know the syntax above is at index.htm when using bbUI lib

If only doing alerts on syntax above is not visible. When using a lot of lines of code on a page whether it should be incorporated into index.htm like the statement above?

How if i use my sample code :

```
$("#DropDownList2").hide();
    $("#pertama").change(function () {
        if ($("#pertama option:selected").text() == "- Pilih Data -") {
            $("#DropDownList2").hide();
            $("select[id$=DropDownList2] > option").remove();
        }

        if ($("#pertama option:selected").text() == "Keren") {
            $("#DropDownList2").show();
            $("select[id$=DropDownList2] > option").remove();
            $("#DropDownList2").append($("<option>" + ("Hyderabad") + "</option>"));
            $("#DropDownList2").append($("<option>" + ("Vijayawada") + "</option>"));
            $("#DropDownList2").append($("<option>" + ("Karimnagar") + "</option>"));
        }
        if ($("#pertama option:selected").text() == "Jelek") {
            $("#DropDownList2").show();
            $("select[id$=DropDownList2] > option").remove();
            $("#DropDownList2").append($("<option>" + ("Madhurai") + "</option>"));
            $("#DropDownList2").append($("<option>" + ("Chennai") + "</option>"));
        }
        if ($("#pertama option:selected").text() == "Tidak Tahu") {
            $("#DropDownList2").show();
            $("select[id$=DropDownList2] > option").remove();
            $("#DropDownList2").append($("<option>" + ("Bangalore") + "</option>"));
        }

    });
```

Would look very much code in the main file

Is the only way out was to use a function in jQuery?

Comment: As a record, Tim and Bertho are carrying this conversation at the BlackBerry Forum, see http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Using-jQuery-Lib-in-bbUI/td-p/1942769/page/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly...

You can keep the main file clean by having functions declared for each page load. Store your functions in separate js files.

```
ondomready: function(element, id) {
    if (id == 'home') {
        loadHomePage();
    }
}
```

...

```
function loadHomePage() {
    $("#Div1").click(function () {
        alert("Hello world!");
    });
}
```

This is what I do in my app.